# Keeping checkboxes checked with fetch array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

Here is the code which I have on the site, it retrieves each season and then numbers of home wins, win percentage and win lsp which is all fine and it creates a new line in the table for each season.

I then have two columns which filter out the data (Min & Max) which are radio buttons and these work fine, they stay checked after I submit and the values work fine.

The one that I am having problems with is the 'Checkbox' which I need to keep checked after the form is submitted, it only keeps one of the checkboxes checked after I submit it.

```
    <form action='' method='post'>
        <?php
    echo "<table id='stats' width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1'>
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultsseason, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
          echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFCC'>";
          echo "<td align='center'><input type='radio' class ='radio-button' name='seasonmin' value='".$row['season']."'" . ((@$_POST['seasonmin'] == $row['season'])?'checked="checked"':"") . "/></td>";
          echo "<td align='center'><input type='radio' class ='radio-button' name='seasonmax' value='".$row['season']."'" . ((@$_POST['seasonmax'] == $row['season'])?'checked="checked"':"") . "/></td>";
          **echo "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='seasonexc' value='".$row['season']."'/></td>";**
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['season'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['countp'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>$profitwb1<font color='$profitw'>" . $row['counth'] . "</font>$profitwb2</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>$profitwb1<font color='$profitw'>" . $row['WinPer'] . "%</font>$profitwb2</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>$profitwb1<font color='$profitw'>" . $row['WinLSP'] . "</font>$profitwb2</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          }

        echo "</table>";
        ?>
<hr><br>
<input type="submit" value="Update" >
<script type="text/javascript">
        var allRadios = document.getElementsByName('seasonmin');
        var booRadio;
        var x = 0;
        for(x = 0; x < allRadios.length; x++){

            allRadios[x].onclick = function() {
                if(booRadio == this){
                    this.checked = false;
                    booRadio = null;
                }else{
                    booRadio = this;
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var allRadios = document.getElementsByName('seasonmax');
        var booRadio;
        var x = 0;
        for(x = 0; x < allRadios.length; x++){

            allRadios[x].onclick = function() {
                if(booRadio == this){
                    this.checked = false;
                    booRadio = null;
                }else{
                    booRadio = this;
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
```

I have searched and read plenty of posts on keeping them checked but I cannot seem to figure it out! The line which I need help with is..

```
echo "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='seasonexc' value='".$row['season']."'/></td>";
```

and how to keep ALL which are checked, checked after I hit submit!

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes differ from radio buttons in that they're not grouped. Whereas with radio buttons you can only have one of those sharing the `name` attribute checked, with checkboxes you must use different names.

In your case you're printing a bunch of checkboxes with the same `name`, which results in just one of them being submitted. A good convention is to use an array-type `name`, which in your case would be `seasonexc[]`. If you're keeping track of indices, change that to `seasonexc[".$index."]`.

Also, I noticed that with your problematic line the `checked` attribute was missing altogether, thus preventing any of them being checked.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that a simple...

```
if (isset($_POST['seasonexc']) && is_array($_POST['seasonexc']) && in_array($row['season'], $_POST['seasonexc'])) { $checked = "checked='checked'"; } else { $checked = ""; }
```

and then calling $checked has solved the problem! Always the way of trying to overthink it!